# DataGridView not refresh after clicking on refresh button C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Green_Sales_1._0
{
public partial class SupplierFrm : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public SupplierFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

this for inserting record in db

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        textBox5.Text = "";
        textBox6.Text = "";
        textBox7.Text = "";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-        HSN6TIC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopManager;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [ShopManager].[dbo].[supplier]([supName],[cno],[emailId],[supAdd],[city],[pincode])VALUES('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "')", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("Supplier Saved");
            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
            this.dataGridView1.Parent.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            String error = exp.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Database Error : "+error);
        }

    }

    private void SupplierFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.supplierTableAdapter.Fill(this.shopManagerDataSet.supplier);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            string supId = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
            string supName = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
            string cno = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
            string email = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
            string address = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;
            string city = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value + string.Empty;
            string pincode = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value + string.Empty;
            textBox1.Text = supId;
            textBox2.Text = supName; 
            textBox3.Text = cno;
            textBox4.Text = email;
            textBox5.Text = address;
            textBox6.Text = city;
            textBox7.Text = pincode;

        }
    }
```

this is for update the record 
i want to reload datagridview after clicking on refresh button

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-HSN6TIC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopManager;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        try
        { 
            string supid = textBox1.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [ShopManager].[dbo].[supplier] SET [supName] = '" + textBox2.Text + "',[cno] ='" + textBox3.Text + "',[emailId] = '" + textBox4.Text + "',[supAdd] = '" + textBox5.Text + "',[city] = '" + textBox6.Text + "',[pincode] = '" + textBox7.Text + "'WHERE [supId] = '" + supid + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("Supplier Updated");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            String error = exp.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Database Error : "+error);
        }
    }
```

here i want to refresh my Datagridview after clicking Button5

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-HSN6TIC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopManager;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            String str1 = "select * from [ShopManager].[dbo].[supplier] ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables;
            dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : "+ exp);
        }
    }
}
```

}

i was tried lots of solution but these are not working for my code

Comment: why is the `dataGridView1.DataSource` commented out? How is the datagridview bound to the table?

Comment: if i remove comment dataGridView.dataSource then after clicking on refresh button records are invisible

Answer (score 0):

***add this code for refresh the dataGridView***

```
this.supplierTableAdapter.Fill(this.shopManagerDataSet.supplier);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.shopManagerDataSet.supplier; 
this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: The [Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used to render the control. In fact, it calls the `Paint` event. It is useless for data binding. Remove this call.